# Permutations of 10 object string containing only 3 possible objects with restrictions?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, permutations

The question is stated as follows:

**How many 10 letter strings containing only 0's, 1's, and 2's have exactly four 0's and exactly three 2's?**

I understand how to calculate permutations given there are only 2 object types if you will (like bits or consonants/vowels), but how would you do it for 3?

This is what I have:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
10  \\
4  \\
\end{pmatrix}
* 
\begin{pmatrix}
6  \\
3  \\
\end{pmatrix}
* 3^3$$

(Of 10 positions, there are 4 positions occupied by 0s) * (Of 6 remaining positions, there are 3 occupied by 2s) * the rest of the positions with 3 possible objects.

Please help! Thank you.

Comment: Place the $0's$, place the $2's$, the  rest then must all be $1's$.

Comment: If you fill two types the way you have done, the third type will automatically occupy the remaining space, or maybe $3^3$ is a typo for $\binom33$

Comment: "*Exactly four 0's*" means what it says... exactly four of them.  No more, no less.  "*The rest of the positions with 3 possible objects*"  0's are no longer possible in those positions since we can not have any more 0's than were already placed.

Comment: Thank you... I feel stupid lol